# How can you put something in between an if/else statement in java?

Tags: java, if-statement

So I have something like this:

```
if (blah) {
    doSomething();
} else if (blahblah) {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

But I can't do the "something else" unless I insert something in between the "if" and the "if else", and I can't put that something before the "if" because that something needs the "if" to happen before that function takes place. Can someone help?

Comment: Not getting your question, but just a suggestion try switch case

Comment: Is that a tongue twister ?!? Please consider reformatting !

Comment: It would be so easy to understand if you provide one proper example instead of something something.

Comment: why have you added Between tag and didn't get what you want to ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 if instead of if and if-else.

```
if (blah) {
doSomething();
} 
dosomethingyouwant();
if (blahblah && !blah) {
doSomethingElse();
}
```