# Execute Code Between If and Else-if Statement in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I got this code:

```
if (conditionX) {

                    doX();
                }



else if (conditionY) {
                    boolean isSomethingTrue = findOutIfSomethingIsTrue();
                    if (anotherConditionIsTrue) {
                        doY();
                    }
                }

XYZPojo xyzPOJO = getXYZPOJO();    

else if (xyzPOJO.getValueX().contains("xyz")) {  // <- eclipse wants me to delete this 'else' statement

                    doXYZ();

                }
```

When I run this code eclipse complains that `"Syntax error on token "else", delete this token"`. I understand this is because I have the code:

```
boolean conditionXYZ = checkIfXYZIsTrue();
```

between both `else if` statements. But I cannot check the value of `conditionXYZ` unless I set the value of `conditionXYZ` in between both `else if` statements.

The only other similar question I found on SO is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076569/how-can-you-put-something-in-between-an-if-else-statement-in-java) and it suggests to use two if statements. The problem is I don't want `conditionXYZ` to be evaluated if `conditionY` is true.

My other option is to use two `if statements` and add a return statement for each if statement. But I do not find this solution to be elegant in terms of code design.

My third option is to  `checkIfXYZIsTrue()` before executing any of the if statements but this is not efficient because if `conditionY` is true we don't need to check `conditionXYZ`.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what exactly is conditionXYZ ?

Comment: think about additional `{ }` in the middle. Sorry, i cant understand algoritjhm

Answer (score 4):

Java syntax doesn't allow you to have statements between chains of if/else (that's not in their respective blocks).

You can execute your third condition in the `else if` condition:

```
if (conditionX) {
    doX();
} else if (conditionY) {
    boolean isSomethingTrue = findOutIfSomethingIsTrue();
    if (anotherConditionIsTrue) {
        doY();
    }
} else {
    XYZPojo xyzPOJO = getXYZPOJO();
    if (xyzPOJO.getValueX().contains("xyz")) {
        doXYZ();
    }
    //reuse xyzPOJO
}
```

Alternatively, the last `else` can still look like:

```
} else if (getXYZPOJO().getValueX().contains("xyz")){
    doXYZ();
}
```

Comment: I had done this initially however  checkIfXYZIsTrue() actually returns and object and I'm evaluating one of the fields of the object as in objectX.getField() and I'm checkinf if the field contains a certain value (I edited the code in my OP for simplicity) . I also need to use this field in the final else if statement -- this means I would need to get this value twice if I put it in the else if condition.. one in the condition and once in the actual block

Comment: Then you can call put the call to `checkIfXYZIsTrue()` inside the final `else` and have a nested `if/else` in the final `else`.  If you update the question with that info, I can update my answer.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty old, but seeing as no one gave the answer I would have, I figured I would post my answer incase anyone else finds their way here looking for options.

> The problem is I don't want conditionXYZ to be evaluated if conditionY is true.

You could use a ternary operator to check that conditionX and conditionY are false before evaluating conditionXYZ above the if/else statements.

```
//Evaluates xyzPOJO only if conditionX and conditionY aren't true, otherwise set xyzPOJO to null
XYZPojo xyzPOJO = conditionX==false && conditionY==false ? getXYZPOJO() : null;

if (conditionX) {
    doX();
}
else if (conditionY) {
    boolean isSomethingTrue = findOutIfSomethingIsTrue();
    if (anotherConditionIsTrue) {
        doY();
    }
}
else if (xyzPOJO.getValueX().contains("xyz")) {
    doXYZ();
}
```